Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) When trying to make JS mastery T-Shirt Project
Trying to make JS Mastery T-Shirt Project and Trying to enter prompt which is then supposed to use the DALLE API and generate an image for me, but I keep getting an error.
All the code is below:
import express, { response } from 'express';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import OpenAI from 'openai';

dotenv.config();

const router = express.Router();

const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY // This is also the default, can be omitted
});


router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({ message: "Hello from DALL.E 2.0" })
})

router.route('/').post(async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { prompt } = req.body;  
      
      const response = await openai.createImage({
        prompt,
        n: 1,
        size: '1024x1024',
        response_format: 'b64_json'
      });

      const image = response.data.data[0].b64_json;

      res.status(200).json({ photo: image });

    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      res.status(500).json({ message: "Something Went Wrong" })
    }
})

export default router;


This is a screenshot of the error:
enter image description here

What's the error? Please provide the error message

I provided a SS of the error
